# JavaScript comparison in if not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code to check maximum values of cars. But Whenever I select 10 in the table I didn't get the max value as 10 corresponding to the car.It is working good for other values except 10.

I debugged with alert and then I found the control is not at all entering in if condition even when the `index[k] > max`?

```js
function findTop() {
  var cars = ["Hyundai", "Maruti Suzuki", "Honda", "Chevrolet", "Tata"];
  var index = [cars.length];
  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var list = document.getElementsByName(cars[i]);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

      if (list[j].checked == true) {
        index[i] = list[j].value;
      }
    }
  }

  var max = 0;
  var maxIndex = 0;
  var text = "";
  for (var k = 0; k < index.length; k++) {
    alert(index[k] + " &nbsp; " + max);
    if (index[k] >= max) {
      alert(index[k] + " &nbsp; " + max);
      max = index[k];
      alert("max" + max);
      maxIndex = k;
    }
  }

  for (var l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
    if (max == index[l]) {
      text = text + "&nbsp" + cars[l];
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + max;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
      <td align="center">7</td>
      <td align="center">8</td>
      <td align="center">9</td>
      <td align="center">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Hyundai</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Maruti Suzuki</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Honda</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Chevrolet</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Tata</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11" align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Top" onclick="findTop()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Sorry, I dont know how to add Jsfiddle link? Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could be because your loop only goes to `10`, elements after that aren't iterated over. You should be using `list.length` instead.

Comment: No, It is starting from begining.

Comment: And `index.length` makes no sense, `index` seems like it should be an integer

Comment: Oh wait, you're strangely just overwriting `index` inside the other loop. This makes no sense ?

Comment: First suggestion done ,no luck  and index is assigned as array in first loop.

Comment: As a sidenote, a name with a space probably isn't valid.

Comment: You're complicating this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/83ma09cs/**

Comment: Yes thats ok But I want car names also for which the value is maximum.

Comment: Easy -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/83ma09cs/1/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values are all strings; `"10"` (the string) will never be greater than the string-compared values `"9"`, etc.

You need to make sure your comparisons are numeric, which you can do like so:

```
if (+index[k] >= max) {
```

```js
function findTop() {
  var cars = ["Hyundai", "Maruti Suzuki", "Honda", "Chevrolet", "Tata"];
  var index = [cars.length];
  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var list = document.getElementsByName(cars[i]);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

      if (list[j].checked == true) {
        index[i] = list[j].value;
      }
    }
  }

  var max = 0;
  var maxIndex = 0;
  var text = "";
  for (var k = 0; k < index.length; k++) {
    console.log(index[k] + "  " + max);
    console.log(typeof index[k]);
    if (+index[k] >= max) {
      console.log(index[k] + " " + max);
      max = index[k];
      console.log("max " + max);
      maxIndex = k;
    }
  }

  for (var l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
    if (max == index[l]) {
      text = text + "&nbsp" + cars[l];
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + max;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table border="1px" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
      <td align="center">7</td>
      <td align="center">8</td>
      <td align="center">9</td>
      <td align="center">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Hyundai</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Hyundai" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Maruti Suzuki</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Maruti Suzuki" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Honda</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Honda" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Chevrolet</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Chevrolet" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Tata</td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="1">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="2">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="3">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="4">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="5">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="6">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="7">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="8">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="9">
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="Tata" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="11" align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Top" onclick="findTop()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: yes you are right? But why values are coming as string?

Comment: Per the spec, they always are: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html#input.radio.attrs.value ; if you use them in a way that forces a numeric conversion, you'll get a number. You weren't doing anything to cause that.

Comment: Yes, `parseInt()` would work, if you find that more readable. It solves the same problem.